# PgBouncer too many client connections for select()

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I have created PostgreSql v12(`port 5432`) and pgbouncer v1.9(`port 6432`). Then I have created a new test database on the pgbouncer server. I followed these steps:

1. ```
   pgbench -h localhost -p 6432 -U postgres -i -s 150 test
   ```

   it has created pgbench tables.
2. ```
   pgbench -p 6432 -U postgres -c 200 -j 2 -P 60 -t 1000 -d test
   ```

   if i use `-c 85` it will run without error. When i increase `-c` to more than 85 or 90 I'm getting `too many client connections for select()`.
3. I have configured  `pgbouncer.ini` and `postgresql.conf` files. 
   On pgbouncer I have added

   ```
   test = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test & pool_mode = transaction,max_client_conn = 10000, default_pool_size = 20
   ```

   in `postgresql.conf` I increased `max_connections` from 100 to 1000 and `shared_buffers` from 128 to 256MB.

   [PgBouncer.ini](https://pasteboard.co/IYNGiSJe.png)
   [Cmd ss](https://pasteboard.co/IYNOrfu.png)
   [PgBouncer](https://pasteboard.co/IYNOJTE.png)
   [postgres.conf](https://pasteboard.co/IYNP1T4.png)
   [db](https://pasteboard.co/IYNPeQh.png)

I would like to  vacuum that database with more than 100 clients.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "vacuum a database with a client"?

Comment: What is your OS?  How did you install PostgreSQL and pgbouncer?  Please don't post images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i use -c 85 it will run without error. When i increase -c to more than 85 or 90 I'm getting too many client connections for select().

The text "too many client connections for select()" occurs in `pgbench` client, and not in either postgresql server nor pgbouncer (that I can find, they might be pieced together from smaller strings).  So whatever is going on is going on inside pgbench.  But, it isn't clear what that actually is, as the command you show certainly should not need more than 1024 file descriptors.

Why inject pgbouncer into this at all?  If you want all connections open and in use simultaneously, pgbouncer has nothing to offer you.  Do you get the same error if you point pgbench directly at the database?

> I would like to vacuum that database with more than 100 clients.

Why?

Comment: I wanted to see the **CPU** differences between pgbouncer and postgre. I have loaded connections via pgbecnh to the pgbouncer and my postgresql server.I have used this configurations for the other laptop and it has run without errors. Thanks alot for your answer.